# Force reload client side code on server startup

Tags: gwt

I am building an intranet application with GWT, gilead and Hibernate, and Tomcat.

As I am actively calibrating the application based on the users' feedback, I have to put on changes and restart tomcat quite often. I was wondering how I can seemlessly make these changes available to the client side. (For the moment I always ask them to refresh after I restart tomcat).

Since the application is client-side (js) based, the client has the application code. Imagine the scenario where he has the application open, and I upload a new version and restart. After the restart, the user can perfectly go on using the application as he has the page open, but he is executing the old code. How can I make the client aware of the new code? I guess just invalidating the session and redirecting the user to the login page won't do that, as the js code won't be refreshed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

As you mention the application will continue to work after the server side update. Even calls to the new version on the server might work if the interface was not changed.

A possible solution is to have a comet connection open, for example with [Atmosphere for GWT](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere). At any time when you have deployed a new version you broadcast an event to the active clients. Clients applications will receive this broadcast and act on it, prompting the user to refresh. You could also use this mechanism to pass messages to active clients, like upcoming server maintenance times.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll give it a try.
What about commercial applications, like say Gmail. When they pull out a new feature, I believe I won't see it, even if it gets available in my region, unless I start a new session, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, As long as you don't refresh the browser you won't see the new features, as it requires the new version to be downloaded just like with a new version of your GWT application.